# Save multiple arrays as columns into a csv file

Tags: php, arrays, csv

I want to write mutliple arrays in one output csv, in which each array represents a column. If I use two loops, the output is below the output from the firt loop..

My code is:

```
$fp = fopen('output.csv','w');

foreach ($ordernumber as $line)  {
    fputcsv($fp,explode(',',$line));
}

foreach ($currency as $line)  {
    fputcsv($fp,explode(',',$line));
} 

fclose($fp);
```

and here the output:

```
item_sku
1126204
1126220
1126230
1126250
1126252
1126256
1126257
1126258
1126260
1126261
1126116.54
currency
EUR
EUR
EUR
EUR
EUR
EUR
EUR
EUR
EUR
EUR
EUR
EUR
```

So, but i need the output side by side - like an regular csv file.

Does anyone have a start for me?

Comment: First prepare the data, then you store it.

Comment: How do you generate the arrays in the first place

Comment: I can only rate now, since my reputation is now high enough

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the lines in both arrays match each other i.e. line 1 = line 1 you have to do it in one loop. One way would be to use the index of the array you are processing to access the other array.

```
$fp = fopen('output.csv','w');

// add col headings    
fputcsv($fp,[ 'item_sku','currency' ]);

foreach ($ordernumber as $idx => $line)  {
    fputcsv($fp,[ $line,$currency[$idx] ]);
}
```

> But I would start by looking at how you managed to generate 2 arrays that contain related data but are not the same array and fix that

Comment: It's also weird how "item_sku" and "currency" appeared in their file. It might need cleaning. +1 nonetheless.

Comment: @FirstOne Yes that bothered me also, but we can only deal with what we are given :)

Comment: @FirstOne Put something in to cover that off

Comment: Hey, thx for this solution, it worked. Sry that i havent given more information, but i thought thats are enough.. :D

The Arrays are build with a other csv i have read, now i need to write this values in a new csv in a other order. But The answer from @RiggsFolly is the solution, great thank!

Comment: And i have create two Arrays ( there are total of more than 50 arrays for each line in the csv ). I thought, if i read a csv its the best way to create one array for each column :0 and there are my problem, i can read in column but must to write in lines ?!

Answer (score 0):

here is 1 way to do this, you have to create an array for every line, then put those into csv:

```
//first create a array like this.
//manually
$mycsv[1] = array('EUR', '1126261');
$mycsv[2] = array('EUR', '1128961');
$mycsv[3] = array('EUR', '1126791');

//programitically; assuming both array are equally based on line by line rows
$mycsv = array();
for ($i=0;$i<count($arr1);$i++){
     $mycsv[$i] = array($arr1[$i],$arr2[$i]);
}

$fp = fopen('output.csv','w');
foreach ($mycsv as $line) {
   fputcsv($fp, $line, ',');
}
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: But the probelm is the OP does not have an array like that!

Answer (score 0):

To complete @RiggsFolly answer, you can do this if yours arrays doesn't have the same indexes :

```
// Check your two arrays have the same size
if (count($ordernumber) === count($currency)) {

    $fp = fopen('output.csv','w');
    foreach ($ordernumber as $line)  {
        fputcsv($fp, [$line, array_shift($currency)]);
    }
    fclose($fp);
}
```